# Filter Multivalue Parameter on Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

So I have a multiple value parameter than contains 3 options. >250K, <250K, >2M. 
I also have a table that consists of multiple columns. [image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]. Because the parameter is a multivalue, i am having difficulties filtering the dataset.

I need to filter the dataset by checking, (if > 250K is selected, filter the dataset accordingly), (if < 250K is selected, filter the dataset accordingly) and (if > 2M is selected, filter the dataset accordingly).

I was told to use a join and split on the parameter within the (>250K condition, then do a contains to see if it contains any of the parameter values) but I am not as advanced in my knowledge of coding to be able to do that.

Any Suggestion? Thanks in Advance

I previously tried the method below but then i came to realise that it wont work because the parameter is a multi value.

[image]

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you need the parameter to be multivalue? 2. Do you want the parameter to filter your dataset at the query?

Comment: Yes, the parameter needs to be a multi value where you can select multiple options when the report has been ran. And yes i would also like the parameter to filter the dataset at query

Answer (score 7):

I know its been a while since you raised this, you were on the right track but all you should need to do is add a filter to the Tablix on the field you will be filtering, use the 'in' operator and in the Value type [@Yourparametername] the square brackets and case sensitivity are important. Also ensure the expression type is correct, in your case it looks like you are using Integer. The image should help.[image: Tablix]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use multi-parameters, In the dataset, you can read parameter value using `JOIN`.

**Example:**

If you want to read multiple values for `@MyParamter` in a dataset given in the following example:

**Dataset Parameters**
[image]

you need to use `=JOIN(Parameters!myMultiParamter.Value,",")` as an expression to read all selected values in CSV form.

**Expression**
[image]

Now the @ParameterValues param has all selected values as comma separated values and you can use them in your dataset code as per design requirements.

**Note:** It's not necessary to use a comma but u can use anything you want to separate values.

Comment: Hi there. I appreciate taking the time to provide me with a solution. I tried this in my dataset, but it still wont work. It provides me with an error specifying "Cannot read the next data row for the dataset"

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query where should look like

```
Where
(
(0 IN (@Parameter) AND ValueColumn<250000)
OR
(1 IN (@Parameter) AND ValueColumn>=250000)
OR
(2 IN (@Parameter) AND ValueColumn>=2000000)
)
```

One parameter

[image]

Two parameters

[image]

All parameters

[image]

Comment: This method doesn't work because it is a multi value parameter. When you "Select All" it breaks

Comment: It's tested that it works, see the attached images. What exactly do you mean by "it breaks"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you return the value you can also use charindex or patindex* and look for where the value in your where clause is a pattern where the index number is `> 0` .  For instance if the returned string from SSRS is `'01,02,03'` and then your where clause has something like this `right(field, 2)` which would result in value `'03'`.  you change your where clause to be where `patindex('%' + right(field, 2) + '%', @returnedstring) > 0` which will give you results.  The keeps you from having to parse apart the `@returnedstring` parameter in your sql code.